# Combine two Private Sub WorkSheet_Change on one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping that you can help me. I have a workbook that I'm trying to get to do two things based on one drop down selection. In the selection I have 1, 2, or 3. and based on that I'd like to have some rows on that page hide, along with certain sheets.

I was able to get the certain rows to be hidden using the first section. and I was able to get the sheets to hide using the second section. I've tested them in different workbooks and they work. Is there a way that I can combine them?

I really appreciate any insight into this issue

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("$B$8:$C$8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "1": Range("A35:A42,A50,A55:A57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                     Rows("12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Is = "2": Range("A35:A42,A50,A55:A57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("12").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    Case Is = "3": Range("A12,A35:A42,A50,A55:A57").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Application.Volatile

Select Case Worksheets("INPUT").Range("B8").Value

    Case "1"
        Worksheets("A").Visible = False
        Worksheets("B").Visible = True
        Worksheets("C").Visible = False
        Worksheets("D").Visible = False
        Worksheets("E").Visible = True
        
    Case "2"
        Worksheets("A").Visible = False
        Worksheets("B").Visible = False
        Worksheets("C").Visible = True
        Worksheets("D").Visible = True
        Worksheets("E").Visible = False
        
    Case "3"
        Worksheets("A").Visible = True
        Worksheets("B").Visible = True
        Worksheets("C").Visible = False
        Worksheets("D").Visible = False
        Worksheets("E").Visible = False


End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Move the code for each `Case` in code 2 into the corresponding `Case` in code 1.

Comment: Side notes: `ActiveSheet.Activate` is redundant. `Range(Target.Address)` ---> `Target`.

Comment: Is the `ActiveSheet` from the first code the same as the `INPUT` worksheet from the second code? Please, do clarify if not.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 - the same sheet!

Comment: A slight problem with your first code is that an error will occur if both cells are changed at the same time. In such a case, what should be considered as the value: the value in `B8` or in `C8`? Could you explain why you're using two cells in the first place?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - sorry for any confusion, it's actually a merged cell. so they're the same

Answer (score 0):

I would create two sub-routines for hiding rows and hiding sheets. Both take the value from your target-range (1, 2 or 3) and act accordingly.

Advantage: when you read the code in worksheet_change event you immediately understand on a high level what is happening without reading detailed code.

Within the sub-routines I removed the "select case" to avoid duplicate code. And in case there are more rows or sheets to be handled you only have to adjust that in one place.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("$B$8:$C$8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    hideShowSpecialRows Target.value
    hideShowSpecialSheets Target.value
End If
    
End Sub

'These routines could also go into a normal module
Public Sub hideShowSpecialRows(value As Long)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXXXX")   'adjust to your needs
    
    ws.Rows(12).Hidden = CBool(value = 1 Or value = 3)
    
    Dim arrRows(2) As String, i As Long
    arrRows(0) = "35:42"
    arrRows(1) = "50"
    arrRows(2) = "55:57"
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrRows)
        ws.Rows(arrRows(i)).Hidden = CBool(value = 2 Or value = 3)
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub hideShowSpecialSheets(value As Long)
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("A").Visible = CBool(value = 3)
        .Worksheets("B").Visible = CBool(value = 1 Or value = 3)
        .Worksheets("C").Visible = CBool(value = 2)
        .Worksheets("D").Visible = CBool(value = 2)
        .Worksheets("E").Visible = CBool(value = 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Change for Hiding Rows and Workhseets

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const sCellAddress As String = "B8"
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Intersect(Range(sCellAddress), Target)
    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
        ShowHide sCell
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowHide( _
        ByVal SourceCell As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ShowHideRanges SourceCell
    ShowHideWorksheets SourceCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ShowHideRanges( _
        ByVal SourceCell As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = SourceCell.Worksheet
    Dim sValue As Long: sValue = CLng(SourceCell.Value)
    ws.Range("35:42,50:50,55:57").EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(sValue - 1) ' F,T,T
    ws.Range("12:12").EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(sValue Mod 2) ' T,F,T
End Sub

Sub ShowHideWorksheets( _
        ByVal SourceCell As Range)
    Const dNamesList As String = "A,B,C,D,E"
    Dim dNames() As String: dNames = Split(dNamesList, ",")
    Dim sValue As Long: sValue = CLng(SourceCell.Value)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = SourceCell.Worksheet.Parent
    wb.Worksheets(dNames(0)).Visible = CBool(sValue = 3) ' F,F,T
    wb.Worksheets(dNames(1)).Visible = CBool(sValue <> 2) ' T,F,T
    wb.Worksheets(dNames(2)).Visible = CBool(sValue = 2) ' F,T,F
    wb.Worksheets(dNames(3)).Visible = CBool(sValue = 2) ' F,T,F
    wb.Worksheets(dNames(4)).Visible = CBool(sValue = 1) ' T,F,F
End Sub
```